# Regarding to recursive functions, how this can be fixed?

Tags: c#

Please help me correct this code which wants to check if in any subfolders of removable drive there is a specific file.

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

        foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
        {
            if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
            {
                string[] dr = Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:");
                for (int i = 0; i <= dr.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    parisa(dr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void parisa(string address)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(address);
        for (int i = 0; i <= files.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            if(files[i].IndexOf("autorun.inf") != -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The USB is Viral");
            }
            else{
                MessageBox.Show("The USB is Safe");
            }
        }

        string[] z = Directory.GetDirectories(address);
        for (int i = 0; i <= z.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            parisa(z[i]);
        }
    }
    }
```

This code does not work correctly. I made an "autorun.inf " subfolder but it shows that it is safe!

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: this code does not work correctly. I made an "autorun.inf " subfolder but it shows that it is safe !

Comment: Is the drive letter really "F:"?

Comment: _" I made an "autorun.inf " subfolder"_ but you're using code that checks file-names not directory-names.

Comment: yes the drive letter is F: ,i got the issue you are completely right Tim Schmelter

Comment: "Fix my code" questions is not good fit for SO. If you really need to do something like this than [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that recursively search all items seem to be what you need: `Directory.GetFiles(@"f:\", "autorun.inf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count != 0`

Answer (score 2):

You say that the program does not detect a folder named `autorun.inf`. That's because you don't discriminate on the names of folders. You only discriminate on the names of files. Add a check on the name of the directory to the start of the `parisa` method.

For your test you should also use the `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` because filenames are not case sensitive on Windows.

Something like this appears to be what you want:

```
private void parisa(string directory)
{
    if(directory.IndexOf("autorun.inf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The USB is Viral");
    }
    ....
}
```

Obviously this test of the directory name is in addition to the test of the filenames.

Your `for` loops are a bit unusual. Iterating over arrays is usually done with a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
{
    ....
}
```

Beyond that, your use of message boxes to provide feedback is impractical and badly implemented. You show a message box for every single object that you encounter. As soon as you find a file that does not contain the magic filename you show a message box. And then again for the next file. And so on.

You really need to change your recursive function so that it returns a boolean if it finds the magic filename. And show the message box outside the recursion. Something like this:

```
private bool find(string directory, string target)
{
    if (directory.IndexOf(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
        return true;

    foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
        if (filename.IndexOf(target, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
            return true;

    foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        if (find(subdir, target))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

---

There seems to be quite a lack of clarity here. In the comments, apparently all you want to do is search for files with the name `autorun.inf`. That is trivial with:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\", "autorun.inf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: I still have the same message that says it is safe !! even adding this piece of code ..Can anyone tell me how can i fix it?

Comment: What did your debugging tell you?

Comment: the messagebox apprears to say that the usb in safe !! i made this folder myself !

Comment: Yes. What does your debugging tell you? Please tell me that you know what debugging is.

Comment: Sorry i assume you mean what errors i get, if that is what you are asking i should say i have no errors! i just don't get the right answer

Comment: I'm asking you what your debugging told you. Please don't tell me that you asked the question without doing any debugging.

Comment: +1 - nice writeup. Also unclear why Parisan wants to re-implement recursive [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: @Alexei He seems to want to pick up dir names too. Probably he's not aware of the functionality already available in the framework.

Comment: in my path F: , there are some files and folders inside my folders there are some other subfolders and inside the subfolders there is a text file autorun.inf . all i want to do is my program to detect this text file now , is there some one who can write this piece of code if mine is wrong?!

Comment: The code in my answer will do that. As will GetFiles(). You need to stop blaming us.

Comment: Please dont take me wrong. There is misunderstanding here , i am not blaming anyone, i do appreciate your reply. all i can not figure out is why it doesnt work for me

Comment: So, instead of editing my answer to say thanks, you might accept the answer.